# In AlloyUI (or YUI3 I suppose), how do I trigger a change event when checking a radio button using setAttribute?

Tags: liferay, liferay-6, alloy-ui

Changing the value of a radioButton using setAttribute('checked',true) changes the value of the radio button, but does not fire a change event.

This does not seem to be limited to YUI or AlloyUI (see for instance [Detecting a change in radio button/checkbox state](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5613278/detecting-a-change-in-radibutton-checkbox-state)).

To work around that issue, I would like to programmatically fire a change event when I set the value of my radio button.

How can I do that in Alloy UI (I am using Liferay 6.1 GA2) ?

Thanks
Alain

Some specifics:

the html:

```
<aui:input type="radio" label="${viewMenuItem.label}" value="${viewMenuItem.value}"
   id="${messageWallDisplay.newMessageOptionName}${viewMenuItem.value}"
   name="${messageWallDisplay.newMessageOptionName}" data="${viewMenuItem.dataMap}"
   checked="${viewMenuItem.value == messageWallDisplay.newMessageOptionDefaultValue}"/>
```

the event delegation setup
(I also tried event callback on the radiobuttons):

```
  messageTypeRadioGroup.delegate('change', function (event){
     var option = event.currentTarget;
     if (option.get("checked")==true){
        showHideUserSelection(option);
     }
  }, 'input[type=radio]');
```

The setAttribute that doesn't trigger the change event:

```
MWC.newMessageDefaultOption.setAttribute('checked',true);
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This answer here looks like what you're trying to accomplish: [Javascript: simulate a click on a link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/648928/javascript-simulate-a-click-on-a-link)

If `MWC.newMessageDefaultOption` is your radio node, you can just do something like this:

```
MWC.newMessageDefaultOption.simulate('change');
```

As noted in the comment Simulate is for testing purposes. For best practice:

```
var doThingsOnChangeFunc = function(arg1, arg2) {
    // do things!
}

myNode.on(
    'change',
    function(event) {
        var arg1 = event.currentTarget;
        var arg2 = "something";

        doThingsOnChange(arg1, arg2);
    }
);
```

Then later down when you are programmatically changing your radio button\checkbox:

```
myNode.setAttribute('checked', true);

doThingsOnChange(arg1, arg2);
```

Comment: I could not get this to work, the change event would still not trigger. I wonder if this has to do with simulate being developed for testing purposes, and yahoo [warning against using it in user-facing code](http://yuilibrary.com/yui/docs/event/simulate.html#faking).

Comment: Interesting, I did not read close enough. But the best option would be to just call the method that is also handling your change event. See my updated answer.

Comment: That's actually what I ended up doing. Thanks !

Answer (score 0):

I ended up refactoring the code, replacing MWC.newMessageDefaultOption variable by a callback: a function that selects the default radio button and performs the same followup actions as in the event handler.

Answer (score 0):

Please try below code,

```
var allRadios = A.all( "input[type='radio']" );
        allRadios.on( 'change', function(e) {
            var portletNamespace='<portlet:namespace/>';
            var selectedRadioButtonValue = e.currentTarget.get('value');
            // add your custom code here
    });
```

Above code add change event to all radio button and when change event occurs it will execute code inside function.

Please let me know if you need anything more

Comment: Thanks Pritesh.
I no longer have the initial code (since I refactored the whole thing) but will try your code. Will certainly come in handy at a later time.

Comment: I tried this code, and couldn't get it to work. The change of the checked status through code does not trigger the change event.